# MPSImageGaussianBlur Returning nil on A7 Devices

Tags: ios, metal

While using `MPSImageGaussianBlur`, I noticed it the init was returning `nil` for A7 devices (tested on 2 iPad Airs and iPhone 5S), but fine on other newer gen devices (tested iPad Pro [big], and iPhone 6). Is this just an undocumented limitation or am I doing something wrong here?

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, MPS are not supported on A7 devices.

https://developer.apple.com/metal/feature-sets/